# Windows 10 updating to... Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I upgraded my laptop from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 several months ago (back when the upgrade was originally released).  When I turned it on today, it gave the "Updating Windows" screen it had when going from 8.1 to 10.

I've been using Windows 10 for months with no real problems and I don't remember anything out of the ordinary happening last time I shut down.  Why would it try to upgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 10?

EDIT: while it was upgrading, my laptop overheated and shut itself off.  When turning it back on, it went through recovering it's last configuration and then booted into Windows 10. I'm unsure if it will happen again, but would still like to know what may have happened just in case.

Comment: You or someone reverted the upgrade maybe? Or it was a normal Windows update

Comment: @Divin3 unlikely.  I'm the only user, don't know how to do that, and didn't have a desire to it.

Comment: was it like this? http://fossbytes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Windows-10-install-without-windows-update-iso-15.jpg

Comment: or like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlebk63zquI

Comment: @Divin3 it was like the first one ( black background, large progress circle with percent in the middle), but instead of Upgrade, it said Update.

Comment: @DavidStarkey Are you sure it wasn't updating from something like build 10240 to 10586?

Comment: I think @AeroStar is right. It was probabbly updating to a new build.

Comment: @Divin3 Thanks. I will post it as an answer so others can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that your Windows is updating from build 10240 to 10586. Check [this.](http://www.thewincentral.com/windows-10-th2-build-10586-vs-th1-build-10240-what-has-changed/)

Comment: Would this give an upgrade screen that looks like [this](http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTahoardH2RSt4fGfywBVkiFAXA8mgBHDzZwvc7QlKTy222qfC9)

Comment: @DavidStarkey Possibly. I think that might have happened to me, but just in case, check [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/236195/how-to-find-out-which-build-and-version-of-windows-10-you-have/) link and tell me what you see.

Comment: @DavidStarkey yes it would, I had several machines show this upgrade screen when updating to the latest full release build. That was some time ago so I'm surprised it did it *now*, but this is what the update did.